# What is the formal mathematical representation of a "force"?

Tags: vector-spaces, classical-mechanics

In mechanics, it is usual to represent a force by a 3-vector. When it is necessary to consider the turning effect of a force, the 3-vector is commonly "attached" to a point on its line of action. In this way, calculations are easily done. There is some redundancy in this specification, and only 5 independent parameters are needed to pin down the force. But I don't know of any practical way of representing forces as elements in a 5-dimensional vector space. In particular, I don't know how forces could be combined or how the concept of "couple" could emerge in such a formalism. Has a theory of forces as 5-dimensional objects been developed?

Comment: "turning effect"?  You mean like [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque)?

Comment: `Has a theory of forces as 5-dimensional objects been developed?` I would guess a creative interpretation of elements of $\Bbb R^5$ would suffice. I doubt you have to invent an entirely new theory for something so similar to the old one.

Comment: Perhaps you mean a vector field?  Or a tangent space (collection of vectors with fixed basepoints)?  I have also been curious whether force is more naturally a vector, a covector, or what.  I am not a physicist.  Including a sample calculation might make your question more clear.

Comment: What makes you think there are only 5 indepentent parameters are needed? The magnitude of the force must also be specified.

Comment: @rschwieb: Torque describes part of the turning effect of forces, but you need to know also where torque is applied.

Comment: @JohnBentin Sure, it's important for computing the torque, but after you know the torque (it's magnitude and axis of rotation) it doesn't seem like the original point the force was imparted is relevant anymore.

Comment: @Dan: Drop the perpendicular from the origin $O$ to the line of action of the force, meeting it at $A$. Given $A$, whose specification requires 3 parameters, the force may be represented by a 2-vector, in the plane through $A$ perpendicular to $OA$, which points along the line of action.

Comment: @rschwieb: True, for a pure couple acting on a rigid body. But in general we need to know where forces act to determine their turning effect. Consider, for example, a single horizontal force applied perpendicularly to a bar lying on a smooth horizontal plane. How the bar rotates (and shifts linearly) depends on just where the force is applied. In addition, it may be remarked that specifying the magnitude and axis of rotation of a torque needs 5 parameters too.

Comment: @John Bentin: Regarding your last comment/example: in the general case the force is not coplanar with bar, so there are six parameters for the force-torque. In the case of coplanarity [there are only 3 components/degrees-of-freedom of the force-torque](https://books.google.com/books?id=GJRGBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA37), not 5.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin: That's actually a good question. Force-torques (wrenches) are probably best seen as elements of the dual Lie algebra se*(3), where se(3) is the Lie algebra of infinitesimal rigid body transformations in 3D. An entirely analogous case occurs in 2D with se*(2) being the "natural space" for 2D force-torques.

Answer (score 3):

It's still rather unclear to me what you're asking, but it's probably about *force-torque vectors* in the *space of [wrenches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Wrench)* as defined in the so called *screw theory*.

Comment: Interesting reference---but these are six-dimensional objects, not five-dimensional.

Comment: @John Bentin: Per Dan's comment below your question and common knowledge, you need 6 parameters not 5 if you really want to represent a force-torque and not something else. The space of screws itself has dimension 5 (has no modulus). But it's not clear to me what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

A force is a screw in 3D with 6 independent parameters. Four parameters for the 3D line of action of the force (position + direction). One parameter for the pitch (torque parallel to the line of action) and one parameter for the magnitude.

Analytically, a force with direction $\vec{e}$, magnitude $F$, position of a point along the force line $\vec{r}$ and pitch $h=\frac{\tau}{F}$ where $\tau$ is the parallel torque is defined by the force moment vectors of

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{F} &= F \vec{e} \\
\vec{M} & = \vec{r} \times \vec{F} + h \vec{F} \end{aligned} $$

Working backwards, given the above vector pair the following parameters are extracted

- Magnitude $$F = ||\vec{F}||$$
- Direction $$\vec{e} = \frac{ \vec{F}}{F}$$
- Position $$\vec{r} = \frac{\vec{F} \times \vec{M}}{F^2}$$
- Pitch $$h = \frac{ \vec{F} \cdot \vec{M} }{F^2}$$

Just as @RespawnedStuff said, the pair $\hat{f} = (\vec{F},\vec{M})$ is called a wrench in screw theory. It is a screw because geometrically it represents a line with direction and position and a pitch. The magnitude is treated as a homogeneous factor because changing its value does not change the geometry of the force system.

Comment: Is it possible to define a less general type of force where the $\tau$ (or $h$) component is zero?

Comment: Yes, but if you are given a $\vec{F}$, $\vec{M}$ pair you are not guaranteed that there isn't going to be a torque component parallel to the force axis. Also there aren't any nice 5 parameter sets to define this scenario. The above takes the 6 plucker coordinates of a line $(\vec{\ell}, \vec{r}\times \vec{\ell})$, treats the norm of $\vec{\ell}$ as the force magnitude.

Comment: Could the $h\vec F$ term of the second equation be replaced by $\tau\vec e$ so that a pure couple (with $F=0$) could be defined?

Comment: Yes $\vec{M} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F} + \tau \vec{e}$ will produce a screw with pitch $h =\frac{\tau}{F}$

Answer (score 0):

In a [differential geometrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) setting force is represented by a covector field (a differential $1$-form). For example, work is then a path integral of force. In a [vector calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus) setting force is a vector field. The geometrical setting is IMHO the most useful but the vector calculus setting seems to be (the most) widespread.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question asked *in the title* of the OP's post/question. Alas in the body of his post-question, he wants to combine forces with torques in some 5-dimensional way (that nobody but him seems to understand precisely insofar).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear in your post why you say a translational force and point's position don't have full degree of freedom. From your comments:

> Drop the perpendicular from the origin O to the line of action of the force, meeting it at A. Given A, whose specification requires 3 parameters, the force may be represented by a 2-vector, in the plane through A perpendicular to OA, which points along the line of action.

This is wrong.

Let the vector component of the force be $v$ and let $x$ be the point the force is acting on, so that the force is $(x,v+x)$.

Construct the plane through $A, x(v+x)$, which is the normal plane to $OA$ at $A$. Take a 2-vector in this vector space at $A$ over this plane. What is $x$ and what is $v+x$? The most information you can get is by letting $x$ or $v+x$ be parametrized by the 2-vector, and then using a scalar multiple of that 2-vector to get the other vector, but the 2-vector alone is not enough to describe both vectors.

Comment: I am referring to a force which has a *line* of action: a standard concept of rigid-body mechanics. You appear to be talking about something else: perhaps an element of a general force field, which does have a *point* of action and so entails a six-dimensional description.

Comment: Wikipedia defines the line of action as "the line through the point at which the force is applied in the same direction as the [force] vector." That is what I intended to describe. $x$ is the point at which the force is applied, whereas $x+v$ is the force vector displaced by the point at which the force is applied. Thus the line $x(x+v)$ is the line of action.

Comment: @John Bentin: I think I know what your "proof" is saying. You appear to be making an incorrect generalization from 2D to 3D as follows: because in 2D the force-torque has (2x2-1)=3 components/degrees-of-freedom, then in 3D it must have (3x2-1)=5 components/DOFs. The first indication that this thinking is wrong is that in 2D rotations can be described by one component/angle because there's only one axis of rotation perpendicular to the plane, but in 3D you have 3 planes, so you [need 3 angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO(3)#Parametrizations). [continued in the next comment]

Comment: On a more physical-explanation level, a force-torque in 2D is uniquely determined by $F_x$, $F_y$, and the magnitude $r$ of the distance between the support line of $F$ and the center of mass of the object, distance measured on a line passing though the center of mass and perpendicular to the force support line; in turn, the support line of $F$ is uniquely determined by the point $(F_x,F_y)$ and the origin of the reference system. Thus in 2D $F_x, F_y$, and $r$ define a unique force and unique application point for it, so a unique force-torque. [continued in the next comment].

Comment: In 3D however, while you have $F_x, F_y, F_z$ and the origin of the reference system also defining the unique support line, the modulus of distance from the center of mass to this line does not uniquely identify a torque/angle, but describes a cylinder centered on this support line, so this (insofar four-dimensional description) can't be a unique force-torque. In order to fix a unique point on this cylinder you need [two more coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system), so six is the minimum number of parameters needed to uniquely identify a force-torque in 3D.

Comment: This last comment needs some refinement, but I'm busy IRL right now, will get back to you.

Comment: Meh, since we're apparently not convincing John here [probably because of not so good pedagogy], I've "outsourced" the question to the physics site: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166105/elementary-proof-of-the-minimum-number-or-parameters-needed-to-uniquely-identify

Answer (score 0):

With the aid of other answers, particularly that of @ja72, I have gathered the answer to be no: a theory of forces as 5-dimensional objects has not been developed. The reason is that, although a pure force is 5-dimensional, the set of such forces does not have any natural vector-space structure. Rather, the set of forces is a 5-dimensional submanifold (not a subspace) of the 6-dimensional space of screws. This space accommodates also couples, or torques, forming a 3-dimensional subspace, which arise when forces are combined.

Six-dimensional screw space comprises pairs $(\vec M,\vec F)$ of 3-vectors which combine in the usual way. The basic equations are $$ \begin{aligned} \vec{F} &= F \vec{e}, \\
\vec{M} & = \vec{r} \times \vec{F} + \tau\vec{e}, \end{aligned}$$ where $F$ is the magnitude of the (pure) force, $\vec e$ is a unit vector in the direction of the line of action of the force, $\vec M$ is the moment of the screw about the origin, $\vec r$ is the position vector of any point on the line of action of the force, and $\tau$ represents the torque component of the screw.

Pure forces are represented by screws with $\tau=0$: that is, $$\{(\vec M,\vec F):\vec M=\vec r\times\vec F\;\,\text{for some}\;\,\vec r\}.$$ Pure moments are those screws with zero $F$-component. In this formalism, two pure forces may give rise to a moment. Thus $$(\vec r_1\times\vec F_1,\;\vec F_1)+(\vec r_2\times\vec F_2,\;\vec F_2)=(\vec r_1\times\vec F_1+\vec r_2\times\vec F_2,\;\vec F_1+\vec F_2)$$ may be not of the pure-force form $(\vec r\times\vec F,\;\vec F)$.